# Use of real values in anchor margin

Tags: qml, qt5, qt-quick

I was going through the QML documentation which says that the anchor margins can be **real** values. 
e.g.

```
anchor
{
top: parent.top
topMargin: 10 // This is valid
left: parent.left
leftMargin: 80.45 // This is also valid
}
```

But somehow, the real value is getting rounded off to the nearest integer values. Then what is the real use of having a real value for margin?

In case, my UX designer is giving me a real value for margin, how I will be able to translate the same in the code? Or, there is no way to do the same in QML?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it rounding off, but, why would that even be a problem?

Comment: @StephenQuan if UX design is specifying leftMargin as 80.45 and it is getting rounded off to 80, you may not see a visible difference. But don't you think logically it is wrong? Moreover, can I say to my UX designer that QML supports real values?

Comment: Can you explain further why it is a problem? Is there are multiplication/zooming issue? I mean, if you had to, you could always go `property double designerValue: 80.45; anchor.leftMargin: designerValue`. Right, so, you can argue that you've kept the designer value in QML. I don't really understand why it is a problem.

Comment: In my experience, it doesn't round. But obviously you can't just draw one half of a pixel. So Qt interpolates between 80 and 81. How are you determining that it's being rounded? Do you have the same problem if you just use `x` and `y` instead of anchor values?

Comment: My experience: Real values allows you to do math on your margins, windows and other objects, i.e. setting a margin to one-tenth of the window size, without accumulating a lot of rounding errors that would occur with integers.

Comment: Also, as JarMan points out, you can't display half a pixel, but the renderer could us anti-aliasing to simulate half a pixel (maybe now, maybe in the future).

Comment: And third, real values allow the screen units to be other than pixels, like centimeters  (again maybe now, maybe in the future - I don't know)